# Airflow runs manual and scheduled Dag even though max_active_runs_per_dag=1

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Good Day,

we use Airflow to orchestrate runs of our jobs.
The Job in question is usually scheduled for 2:30 and takes quite some time.
Due to a new data source it was expected to run a full day.
Since our jobs don't work parallel we set max_active_runs_per_dag to 1 to ensure that there are no multiple instances of the same job even when it takes more than 24h. In general this seem to work, but not in this case.

What happened:

- We triggered a manual run at 13:00
- at 2:30 (next day) the scheduled run is triggered and runs simultaneously

Expectation:

- The scheduled run should wait for the manual run to finish

More Information:

- The Airflow instance did not restart.
- Airflow version 1.10.2

I thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an open Issue which will be fixed in 2.1 and 1.15.
A workaround was not provided yet.
https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/9975